# What alternatives are there for Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to develop ASP.NET MVC site but I am confused about the use of EF. While developing my database structure/tables will be changed frequently and also after going to the production if anything happened?

If EF not for ASP.NET MVC3 then I would use ....... ?

Comment: Regardless of which ORM you choose (assuming you decide one is necessary,) it might be a good idea to spend some time working out your data model first, so that the number of times your database schema changes (even during development) is reduced.

Comment: @dlev This is certainly a good idea but I can never guess when client changes the requirement. My purpose is to minimize the rework effort.

Comment: that's a fair point. Clients can be pesky :)

Comment: Have you looked at EF code-first? For a frequently changing schema it is quite nice if you want to stay on SQL Server.

Comment: Choosing .NET ORM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Comment: Voting to close based on the official close reason: _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
- [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/)

Don't bother with anything else, in my opinion.

nHibernate is a very mature and open source ORM that can use SQL Server to get data into/out of your ASP.NET MVC (and version) project(s). It is the most direct competitor to EF it terms of popular options in the *ORM* space.

If you like new and cutting edge technology, then give RavenDB a go. It is its own database and doesn't require an ORM. It just saves the class library objects straight to its own DB. Therefore, you don't have database schema migration issues, etc.

I would go for RavenDb IMO. I'm leaving EF because I'm just so sick of SQL Server and all the hoops and barriers to getting my domain models to work nicely with a traditional RDBMS. (And this is after working with SQL Server since '95) ...